# How do I access the version number of the package I'm writing?

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry, python-importlib

I'm trying to build a Python project. I use Poetry to manage dependencies. In my `pyproject.toml`, I have the following:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "gitdida"
version = "0.2.0"
```

My directory structure is like:

```
project-root/
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- src/
|   |-- gitdida/
|       |-- __init__.py
|-- tests/
|   |-- test_script.py
```

I want to be able to access version in the project's code file. However, Poetry itself does not provide access to the code. I look for information on the network, and chatGPT says you can get the version number by `importlib.metadata`:

```
from importlib.metadata import version

def test_version():
    expected = "0.2.0"
    assert version("gitdida") == expected
```

But, after the test I get error:

```
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for gitdida
```

Why can't script find the gitdida package? I've been stuck here a long time.

I asked chatGPT 3.5 and Bard, but neither give me a solution.

Comment: Did you remember to install your project (`poetry install` or `pip install -e .`)? How are you running the tests?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Brian61354270
After I run `poetry install`,the script test passed.
Thanks.